# Django execute specific SQL query to select and monitor data

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have a MySQL database and I'm trying to make a Django app to reach latest data. What I'm trying to do is select latest data in my database and monitoring it, don't need to insert or update anything. I was using pure PHP before it and my query was

```
"SELECT id, source_id, MAX(time) 
 FROM table 
 WHERE id = %s AND source_id = %s",[id],[source_id]
```

I don't have any model in my django app since the table already exists and I just need to reach that data. I search internet and can't find any useful information. Is there any way?

Comment: i can't run this command it says Unknown command: 'syncdb' is that command gives below codes? https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Comment: No sorry for mistake you can use python manage.py inspectdb > models.py which can be used for existing databases

Comment: follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Comment: Oh, so Django creates a model automatically, thank you very much for the help!